# Visual Studio Team Services Online - Repository Branch Templates

Tags: git, azure-devops

I'm using the online version to setup Git Code Repos. When you selet the **Create New Repository** option is there anyway of setting up default branches e.g. master, dev, testing.....

We always have the same set of branches and it is a pain having to set them up seperately each time.

[image]

**EDIT:**

As per the advice from Eddie (Answer) - I have added a Team Service Uservoice. If you think the idea is a good one, then upvote it:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/14830602-repository-branch-templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't any option to configure this when create the new repository. The first branch created or pushed to the repository will be the default branch. You can submit a feature request on [VSTS User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services).